# How can I Change the Domain for URLs with Dynamic Hostname & Proxy Forwarding?

Tags: php, wordpress, proxy, hostname

We use a plugin called "**Dynamic Hostname**" & run a **Wordpress Blog (newest version)**.

To This Wordpress Blog we point 2 Domains:

```
https://blog.domain1.com
https://blog.domain2.com
```

The problem is, **we use Proxy Forwarding**, so:
`https://blog.domain2.com/whatever/` loads & shows - but with the URLs from the Original Domain `https://blog.domain1.com` inside.

That's the Problem, it DOES NOT align the URLs inside the `<head>` and `<body>` to `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` as it should.

Unfortunately, we need a solution to fix this, any ideas? :(

Comment: Tried: define('WP_HOME', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); in wp-config.php?

Comment: @Farkie will try that, good one